# What's the purpose of the "Before=" directive

Tags: systemd

To me it sounds more natural for services that are in some way dependent on others to specify that in their scripts (using `Requires=` and `After=` directives). After all, when writing a service you can't actually know about all the services that might depend on it, but you can know what your service is dependent on.

So the question is: what is the actual purpose of the `Before=` directive? When should it be used?

Answer (score 4):

`Before` and `After` specify ordering constraints between services, they don’t specify dependency constraints between services. So there’s no need to exhaustively document the services which depend upon any given service inside that service’s `Before` statement; as you rightly point out, that’s impossible.

`Before` is used when *you know* that your service must be started before another, known, unit, even when the other unit doesn’t necessarily depend on the service being specified. The important aspect is where it makes sense for the knowledge to be captured. In particular, it’s often used in service descriptions to state that the service must be started before a given *target*, and it’s pretty much the only sensible way to describe ordering constraints between services and targets; for example, `wpa_supplicant@` must be started before the `network` target. Other cases where it’s appropriate include services which “augment” others in some way, where the augmented service can’t be expected to know about the augmenting service; for example, `fwupd` says that it must be started before the `gdm` service, which is OK, but you wouldn’t expect `gdm` to know that it should start after `fwupd` (or worse still, depend on it).